# Grails: One controller for whole class hierarchy?

Tags: grails, data-binding, controller, domain-model

Is it possible to use only one controller for several domain model classes if all those classes are in the same hierarchy (ie: they all inherit from the same base class)?  So for example, can I create a FormController as my controller and have the following domain models be serviced by it:

```
Form
BigForm (inherits from Form)
SmallForm (inherits from Form)
OtherForm (inherits from Form)
```

If this is possible, how do I tell Grails to create the correct domain model object when entering some of the default methods like save, update, delete, etc.?  Or in other words how do I make data binding work correctly with this setup?

Comment: It is not necessary to use several controllers for correct data binding. You just have to use name convention for correct binding. I'm not sure that grails default databinding in hierarchy will work correct, so you need to handle it by the hands.

Comment: Are you using auto scaffolding feature? Otherwise you can use any domain class in any controller you want.